# How can I create a Permission object using the .value int gotten from another Permissions object?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've looked through the docs but I can't seem to find it. How can I create a `Permissions` object with the `.value` int gotten from another `Permissions` object? I'm trying to duplicate permissions from one role to another. I know of another way to do this but I feel like this is the most efficient method, if it's possible.

I am using the discord.py library

I am trying to upload the permissions to a database, otherwise I would do this. For context, I am creating a command to undo the deletion of a role. If a user deletes a role using the delete role command on the bot, it will upload all information pertaining to the role (members, permissions, name, etc..), and the user can use a command to undo the deletion if they regret it later. As far as I know, it's not possible to upload objects to databases.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the perms of a role you can do this:

```py
from discord.utils import get

role_id = "roleID"
role = get(guild.roles, id=role_id)

roleperms = role.permissions
# Then create the role
author = ctx.message.author
await bot.create_role(author.server, name="rolename", permissions=perms)
```

Comment: I am trying to upload the permissions to a database, otherwise I would do this. For context, I am creating a command to undo the deletion of a role. If a user deletes a role using the delete role command on the bot, it will upload all information pertaining to the role (members, permissions, name, etc..), and the user can use a command to undo the deletion if they regret it later. As far as I know, it's not possible to upload objects to databases. That's why I asked this question in this way, I apologize for the confusion. I just edited my question to include this.